# MongoDB connection errors to flask

Tags: angular, mongodb, flask, pymongo

When trying to use Flask, pymongo to create an angular app, i am having issues, in mongosh the data is present and appears correctly in json format, mongod is also running successfully, however for some reason the data will not pull into the app, i have tried many fixes from chatgpt and none of them have helped.

I do not receive the error message which i have included in the try except, the only one i receive is: No data found

```
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
    import json
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    from bson import ObjectId
    import string
    import jwt
    import datetime
    from functools import wraps
    import bcrypt
    from flask_cors import CORS

    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app, resources={r"/api/v1.0/players": {"origins": "http://localhost:4200"}})

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
    try:
        client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/")
        db = client.playerDB5
        players = db.players
        editors = db.editors
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to MongoDB: {e}")

    @app.route("/api/v1.0/players", methods=["GET"])
    def show_all_players():
        try:
            '''page_num, page_size = 1, 15
            if request.args.get("pnum"):
                page_num = int(request.args.get('pnum'))
            if request.args.get("psize"):
                page_size = int(request.args.get('psize'))
            page_start = (page_size * (page_num - 1))'''

            players_cursor = db.players.find()#.skip(page_start).limit(page_size)
            player_list = list(players_cursor)

            # Check if there are no documents
            if not player_list:
                return make_response(jsonify({"message": "No data found"}), 404)
    
            return jsonify(player_list)
        except Exception as e:
            return make_response(jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500)
```

before i started using the angular parts this code was working however even if i remove it now the connection still wont work

Comment: look at `client.playerDB5`. check your database name is `playerDB5` or `playerdb5`. In pymongo distinguish between uppercase and lowercase. Better to use `client["playerDB5"]`